# how to combine 4 tables in spring jpa (Query)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, left-join

I have a data table called RoomBoy, the data is like this

```
"room": {
            "id": 1,
            "roomId": 40,
            "floor": "1",
            "roomNumber": "107",
            "condition": null,
            "status": "Waiting"
        },
        "bedType": {
            "id": 1,
            "bedTypeName": "Twin Bed"
        },
        "roomCategory": {
            "id": 35,
            "categoryName": "Superior"
        },
        "guestName": "RIKO JANUAR"
    }
```

I also have data from a table called RoomBoyDetail

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "roomBoyId": 1,
        "productId": 3,
        "productName": {
            "id": 3,
            "productName": "HORS D’OEUVRE VARIE"
        },
        "qty": 3,
        "description": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "roomBoyId": 1,
        "productId": 4,
        "productName": {
            "id": 4,
            "productName": "CREAM OF VEGETABLES SOUP"
        },
        "qty": 2,
        "description": null
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "roomBoyId": 1,
        "productId": 5,
        "productName": {
            "id": 5,
            "productName": "RAVIOLI AU JUS"
        },
        "qty": 2,
        "description": null
    }
```

I want to combine these 2 tables, with the same id(From RoomBoy) and roomBoyId(From RoomBoyDetail). And my code like this

```
@Query("select new com.acs.pms.model.ObjekRoomBoyDetail(a,b.bedType,b.roomCategory,c.guestName,d.productName,d.qty,d.description) from RoomBoy a left outer join RoomMaster b on a.roomId = b.id "
        + "left outer join ReservationDetail c on a.roomNumber = c.roomNumber where c.checkinStatus = true and c.checkoutStatus = false "
        + "left outer join RoomBoyDetail d on a.id = d.roomBoyId")
        Page<ObjekRoomBoyDetail> getAllDetail(
        Pageable paging);
```

**And i have error unexpected token: left near line 1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a left outer join after the where clause:

```
select new com.acs.pms.model.ObjekRoomBoyDetail(a,b.bedType,b.roomCategory,c.guestName,d.productName,d.qty,d.description) 
from RoomBoy a 
left outer join RoomMaster b on a.roomId = b.id 
left outer join ReservationDetail c on a.roomNumber = c.roomNumber 
where c.checkinStatus = true and c.checkoutStatus = false 
left outer join RoomBoyDetail d on a.id = d.roomBoyId
```

It should be

```
select new com.acs.pms.model.ObjekRoomBoyDetail(a,b.bedType,b.roomCategory,c.guestName,d.productName,d.qty,d.description) 
from RoomBoy a 
left outer join RoomMaster b on a.roomId = b.id 
left outer join ReservationDetail c on a.roomNumber = c.roomNumber 
left outer join RoomBoyDetail d on a.id = d.roomBoyId
where c.checkinStatus = true and c.checkoutStatus = false
```